# Rails 4.0 record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

on my edit action I never rise the record not found if the record does not exist. What I'm doing wrong.

Here is my edit action

```
    class OffersController < ApplicationController

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found        

    def show
        @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    end        

    def edit
        @offer = Offer.find_by(edit_hash: params[:edit_hash])
        @country = Country.find_by(name: @offer.country)
        @states = State.find(:all, :conditions => { country_id: @country })
    end

    private

        def record_not_found
            render text: "404 Not Found", status: 404
        end
    end
```

I always get undefined method `country' for nil:NilClass for my unexist edit record.

Also I raise the record not found on my show action, but I would like to use the 404.html page that I have on my public folder. How can I use this file???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run 'rake db:migrate' from the console to populate your database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your line `@offer = Offer.find_by(edit_hash: params[:edit_hash])` is not responding with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. It's responding with `nil`.

You can see this by opening up your Rails console from your app's directory with `rails c`. In the console, put this in:

`@offer = Offer.find_by(edit_hash: params[:edit_hash])`

You'll see that its output is `=> nil`. You can then type `@offer` and you'll see its output, again, is `=> nil`. Now, put this line into the console:

`@offer = Offer.find(99999)`

You'll see that its output is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Offer with id=99999`.

To fix the problem, add a `!` to your `find_by` calls, so they are like this:

`@offer = Offer.find_by!(edit_hash: params[:edit_hash])`

This will cause Rails to respond with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` instead of `nil`.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, since I needed to change the finder from `.find` to `.find_by_username`, hmmm, `.find` returns a RecordNotFound exception, but `.find_by_...` doesn't

Comment: That's right. [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if one or more ids are not found, and [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) will return `nil` if no record is found.